# How do I turn a dictionary into a 3 column dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am turning a dict into a dataframe. My dict is like `key:[value]`.

Dict example;

`{'StringAwesome': PureWindowsPath('//server/cool.log'), 'StringCool': PureWindowsPath('//server/rad.log')}`

I want three rows like;

`0 -- key -- value`

I used `orient=index`. Which is close, but it gives me;

```
       0
key -- value
```

I'd like to end up with;

```
index -- columnA -- columnB
0     -- key     -- value
```

```py
def build_failmacro_df() -> pd.DataFrame:
    """build a dataframe containing sites with failing macros"""
    sites = get_failing_sites()
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sites, orient='index')
    df.to_csv(Path(r'C:\test.csv')) 
    #return df

build_failmacro_df()
```

How can I achieve? Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].

Comment: @rpanai OP shows you how to reproduce. Create a dict like the example and then use the function. Boom.

Comment: @mozway Refresh your page. All my Python is valid. I think your wording may be off? I think what you meant to ask was - "Please provide a literal example of your Python dictionary."

Comment: There was no dictionary when I commented, at must have cross-posted ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use:

```
sites = {'keyA': ['valueA'], 'keyB': ['valueB']}
df = (pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sites, orient='index')[0]
        .rename_axis('columnA').reset_index(name='columnB')
     )
```

Or:

```
sites = {'keyA': 'valueA', 'keyB': 'valueB'}
df = (pd.Series(sites)
        .rename_axis('columnA').reset_index(name='columnB')
     )
```

Output:

```
  columnA columnB
0    keyA  valueA
1    keyB  valueB
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
import pandas as pd 

my_dict = {"key1": "val_1", "key2": "val_2"}
processed_dict = [(k,v) for k,v in my_dict.items() ] 

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records( processed_dict, columns=['col_1', 'col_2'] )
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  col_1  col_2
0  key1  val_1
1  key2  val_2
```